# Over-voltage prevention not working

Tags: arduino, voltage-divider

I have an system that has a signal that swings to logic level 0(on)-12v(off).

That i'm reading with an Arduino.

The signal is normally held at 12v.

Using a simple circuit like so:

[image: Boad example]

The blue line is the one that swigs.

My question is, why is the Arduino burning out? Issent the diode preventing the 12v from going backwards and hitting the board with 12v? and the ground should draw the 5v away from the board reading logic level 0.

Comment: "the ground should draw the 5v away from the board" - what ground? Please show a complete schematic with _all_ wiring and connections, power supplies etc. What is the device that produces a 12V 'signal'?

Comment: Its just a wire thats meant to be a signal to an ICT printer. The voltmeter shows the blue wire is held at 12.2v and taps ground to pulse the signal.

Comment: Do your Arduino and external device share a ground?

Comment: "Its just a wire..." - the reason I asked for a schematic etc. is that too often what the questioner _doesn't_ tell us is the vital clue. All I can say is that _if_ everything is as you describe then the Arduino should not blow up, but I would not trust a diode to keep voltage spikes out (for a start, it won't block negative voltage).

Comment: @pscheidler Yes and a voltage source.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Problem is I don't have a schematic. and the unit it goes into it the size of a truck. So lets just say its an arcade. How would you recommend I test the line to find any other information?

Comment: From the comments you write, I have no idea about 1) If your are just _reading_ the signal or if you are _controlling_. 2) What does "the ground should draw the 5v away" even mean? VTC unclear until there's some tidying.

Comment: Draw a SCHEMATIC.

Comment: From what I see the analog input is being hit by -12 volts, more than enough to fry it. I believe the analog range at the pins is 0 to + 5 volts, as are many MPU's, including the PIC series. The intent of this circuit is to ground the diode and read it's forward clamp voltage.

Comment: the first sentence mentions `-12V` and the third sentence mentions `12V`  .... which is it?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from your cartoon, you didn't post a proper schematic, but I think your wiring is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmYRgD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Regular diode (like 1N400x) has very slow recovery time, that means 12V will get through it for couple of microseconds which is enough to fry your MCU. Even if you use 1N4148 there is 4ns recovery time, that can be enough to fry your MCU.

**UPDATE:**
There are several ways to do it properly. One of them is to use simple voltage level translator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGQRtX.png)</sup>

Or you can use zener diode with one resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa3c2E.png)</sup>

Or just simple voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIJfFr.png)</sup>

This voltage divider is not usable in car, because voltage could be as high as 14.4V. It is usable only in circuit where you can guarantee 12V voltage level.

There are even other methods. It depends on your needs.

Comment: looks right, what would you recommend I use then? Or how would I change the part?

Comment: Would a schottky diode fare better?

Comment: I would use voltage level translator. It's 1 nmosfet + 2 resistors.

Comment: Trying this, not working: https://ibb.co/fLU9nG

Comment: "Trying this, not working" - Diode is backwards. Perhaps this is why your Arduino fried?

Comment: Whoops, drew it backwards.

Comment: @StevenVenham did you read my answer? What you don't like about that proposed circuits?